# python to pars xml to get value

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces, elementtree

I have a xml response from one of my system where i am trying to get the value using python code. Need experts view on highlighting my mistake.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns3:loginResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.core.product.xxxxx.com/groupService/" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.core.product.xxxxx.com/loginService/" xmlns:ns4="http://ws.core.product.xxxxx.com/userService/"><ns3:return>YWeVDwuZwHdxxxxxxxxxxx_GqLtkNTE.</ns3:return></ns3:loginResponse>
```

I am using the below code of code and had no luck in getting the value - `YWeVDwuZwHdxxxxxxxxxxx_GqLtkNTE` . I haven't used xml parsing with namespace. response.text has the above xml response.

```
responsetree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(response.text))
   responseroot = responsetree.getroot()
   for a in root.iter('return'):
       print(a.attrib)
```

Answer (score 0):

`YWeVDwuZwHdxxxxxxxxxxx_GqLtkNTE` is not in the `attrib`. It is the element `text`

The attrib in this case is an empty dict

See https://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/prog2-2012/docs/diveintopython3/xml.html about parsing XML dics using namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Reference from other answer helped to understand the concepts.

Once I understood the xml structure , Its plain simple. Just adding the output it might help someone in future for quick reference.

`responsetree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(response.text))
 responseroot = responsetree.getroot()
 root[0].text`

Keeping it simple for understanding. You might need to find the `len(root)` and/or iterate over the loop with condition to get apt value. You can also use `findall` , `find` along with to get the interested item.